# Proportionally shrink a DIV similar to a responsive image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This might be a silly questions... but in CSS, a "responsive image" is typically something like this:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Is it possible to use a div (or series of nested divs) instead of an image that behaves the same way that a responsive image does? You would need to define a div with width 1000px and height 200px, but have it proportionally shrink as the container shrinks in width.

Essentially, is it possible to make something like this:

http://codepen.io/jakobud/pen/jEKVRZ

behave like this:

http://codepen.io/jakobud/pen/MYXbZB

Is this possible in any way? If not, why? You obviously can't add `height: auto` to the `div.two` because that would override the DIV's defined height.

One workaround I have considered for this approach, is to create a 1000x200 fully transparent PNG that you would place in your container, which would give the desired results, but it is a total hack. Seems like you should be able to do it with CSS but I'm not sure how.

Also I am looking for a solution that does not require jQuery.

The reason I'm asking for this is becomes sometimes designers have asked for something like this where there is a container that is sized with a certain aspect ratio but there is no background image used. In some cases the designer wants to use a CSS gradient for the background so I can't just use an `<img>` that is the aspect ratio of the container. Obviously I can't rely on the contents (a `<h1>` or something) to dictate the container shape/aspect ratio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`div`s do not intrinsically have an aspect ratio like images, but you can use padding on a wrapper div with an absolutely positioned child to simulate the aspect ratio. This is a common approach for handling responsive videos.

```
.one {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20%; /* 1000:200 */
  height: 0;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/sdsanders/pen/zxaNGQ

Comment: Oh wow, using the padding as a ratio of height to width is really good. Never thought of that. I assumed a padding that used a percent would be X% of the height of the outside container..... Never considered it would be a % of the width...

Comment: @Jakobud percentage vertical padding is actually a percentage of the width of the element, which is extremely unintuitive but allows this little trick to work!

Comment: Never knew that. Thank you for the trick. That is really useful and I've never seen it before.